# Javascript calculate values with multiple inputs not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to calculate values of multiple inputs. Here is my code.

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.total_t').each(function() {
  sum += parseFloat(this.value);
});
$('#debtor_t_o_debtors').val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="numeric total_t" value="12,584,436.86" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="558,718.60" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="9,013.25" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="0.00" type="text">

<input class="numeric" value="" type="text" id="debtor_t_o_debtors">
```

But unfortunately I'm getting 579 as answer which wrong. It would be great help if someone can tell what's the error here.

Comment: Remove the commas, either in the HTML or before parsing the number as float: `sum += parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ""));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `value`s contain commas, and `parseFloat` stops parsing when a comma is found.

Replace each comma with the empty string first:

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.total_t').each(function() {
  sum += parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
});
$('#debtor_t_o_debtors').val(
  sum.toFixed(2)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="numeric total_t" value="12,584,436.86" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="558,718.60" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="9,013.25" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="0.00" type="text">

<br>
<input class="numeric" value="" type="text" id="debtor_t_o_debtors">
```

To add commas to the result after adding, use a regular expression to lookahead for 3, 6, 9, etc digit characters, followed by a `.`:

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.total_t').each(function() {
  sum += parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
});
$('#debtor_t_o_debtors').val(
  sum
    .toFixed(2)
    .replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+\.)/g, ',')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="numeric total_t" value="12,584,436.86" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="558,718.60" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="9,013.25" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="0.00" type="text">

<br>
<input class="numeric" value="" type="text" id="debtor_t_o_debtors">
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with `,` in your input fields, remove it you will get correct total.

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.total_t').each(function () {
    console.log(parseFloat(this.value), this.value);
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
});
$('#debtor_t_o_debtors').val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="numeric total_t"  value="12584436.86" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t"  value="558718.60" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t"  value="9013.25" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t"  value="0.00" type="text">
<input class="numeric" value="" type="text" id="debtor_t_o_debtors">
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the character other than digit and dot with empty

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.total_t').each(function() {
  sum += parseFloat(this.value.replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, ""));
});
$('#debtor_t_o_debtors').val(
  sum.toFixed(2)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="numeric total_t" value="12,584,436.86" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="558,718.60" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="9,013.25" type="text">
<input class="numeric total_t" value="0.00" type="text">

<br>
<input class="numeric" value="" type="text" id="debtor_t_o_debtors">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input value contains comma you first need to remove the comma and then you can add **comma** again into the result if you need.

```js
var sum = 0;
        $('.total_t').each(function() {
          sum += parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
        });
        $('#debtor_t_o_debtors').val(
          sum.toFixed(2).toLocaleString()
        );
```